# Removing an item from a list: Trashcan Icon vs X

Tags: usability, interaction-design, user-behavior, user-expectation, icons

Below I have an example image of a list with two separate icons. I am curious which one conveys the best action of removal from the list, either a trash icon or a closing x.

Specifically, this is being used to remove an entry from a list that the user has added.

*Is there* a better way to display this?

**Note: I do not care about the UX interactions etc, purely the icon representation!**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either will work, but if you want to be as correct as possible, think about the semantics of each.

- **Trash** means "delete this thing"
- **X** means "close this thing"

You decide which is appropriate in your context and watch users to make sure it's not an issue for them.